# Change hook to add_action in a plugin class

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, actions

```
<?php

namespace wp_gdpr_wc\controller;

use wp_gdpr\lib\Gdpr_Container;
use wp_gdpr_wc\lib\Gdpr_Wc_Translation;
use wp_gdpr_wc\model\Wc_Model;

class Controller_Wc {
    const REQUEST_TYPE = 3;

    /**
     * Controller_Form_Submit constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $this, 'checkout_consent_checkbox' ) );
    }   
public function checkout_consent_checkbox( $checkout ) {
        $privacy_policy_strings = Controller_Menu_Page_Wc::get_privacy_policy_strings();

        echo '<div class="gdpr_consent_class"><h3>' . __( 'GDPR permission: ', 'wp_gdpr' ) . '</h3>';

        woocommerce_form_field( 'gdpr_consent_checkbox', array(
            'type'     => 'checkbox',
            'label'    => $privacy_policy_strings[ Controller_Menu_Page_Wc::PRIVACY_POLICY_TEXT_WOO_REQUEST ],
            'required' => true,
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'gdpr_consent_checkbox' ) );

        echo '</div>';
    }
```

I'd like to change the `woocommerce_after_order_notes` hook from the add action with another hook. This is a class from a plugin. I tried to include that file in functions.php and initialize that class in a variable, but I get an error saying `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Controller_Wc' not found in functions.php`

```
$path = get_home_path();
require_once $path . "/wp-content/plugins/wp-gdpr-wc-addon/controller/controller-wc.php";
$clasa = new Controller_Wc();
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $clasa, 'checkout_consent_checkbox' ) );
```

I tried to put controller-wc.php in child theme to overwrite the original one, but this did not work as well.

Comment: You nee to add `use wp_gdpr_wc\controller;` in functions.php file. You can use `$clasa = new wp_gdpr_wc\controller\Controller_Wc();`

Comment: @BikashWaiba, just did, problem is that when I initialize it `$clasa = new wp_gdpr_wc\controller\Controller_Wc();` the action runs one more time, any way to stop that? To be more clear, the action runs twice, one from the initialization and one from the original plugin, then I use remove_action and it removes one of them, the other one still there. I tried to remove it twice but does not work, tried a higher priority, same thing, one of them still there.

Comment: You have `add_action` twice in your code. you can remove `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $clasa, 'checkout_consent_checkbox' ) );` after the class is intantiated

Comment: `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $clasa, 'checkout_consent_checkbox' ) );` is not needed as `add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', array( $this, 'checkout_consent_checkbox' ) );` already triggers when the new instance of the class is created.

Comment: I have just `use wp_gdpr_wc\controller;
$clasa = new wp_gdpr_wc\controller\Controller_Wc();`, no other add_action, just a remove_action.

Comment: I meant you have add action on both of the code snippet above.

Comment: My code now it's just those two lines and I get two instances on the page.